# Как перекинуть по ssh конфигурацию удаленного ПК на локальный ПК? (Ubuntu-Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Задача состоит в том, чтобы с удаленного ПК перекинуть информацию о системе на локальный ПК, с помощью ssh, закинув информацию в файл

```
#!/bin/bash
touch log.txt && lshw > log.txt && scp /home/alk/Документы/log.txt nik@192.168.0.11: && rm -r log.txt
```

У меня получилось сделать нечто похожее, но только с созданием файла и последующим его удалением..Хотелось бы уменьшить потребление ресурсов, иначе с большим объемом данных работа может замедлиться

Answer (score 3):

Можно просто передать данные через трубу и записать в файл на удалённом хосте:

```
lshw | ssh nik@192.168.0.11 'cat >/path/to/file/log.txt'
```

Comment: Можно и без `cat`.

Comment: @0andriy, и как же?